# Horizontal Div inside floats issue

Tags: css, html

For some reason I cannot get the right menu to float right this is a horizontal div menu. the image and the left links are perfect.. the right just doesn't work, the are both in a single div.

I would like it to look like

logo--- link---link--link--link-----------------------------Date & Time

```
#menu {
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;   
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


#left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left li {
    float: left;
}

#left li a {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#right ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right li {
    float: right;
}

#right li span {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#menu img{
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px
}




<div id="menu">
<a href=""><img src="logo.svg"></a>
<div id="left">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
<div id="right">
<ul>
   <li>Date & Time</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to float your block level elements, otherwise they will still take up 100% width. So float `#left` and `#right`.

```css
#menu {
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;   
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


#left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left li {
}

#left li a {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#right ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right li {
  padding-top: 9px;
}

#right li span {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#menu img{
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<a href=""><img src="logo.svg"></a>
<div id="left">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
<div id="right">
<ul>
   <li>Date & Time</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you check out flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You can get a real good understanding from https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/. Give it a read .. :D

```
/* align all direct child of menu, in same horizontal .... */
#menu > * {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

/* float the right component to right, and add a margin to top to bring all to same level */
#right {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
```

```css
#menu {
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;   
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#menu > * {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

#left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left li {
    float: left;
}

#left li a {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#right {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}

#right ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#right li span {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#menu img{
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
 <a href="">
  <img src="logo.svg">
 </a>
 <div id="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>  
  </ul>
 </div>
   <div id="right">
  <ul>
     <li>Date & Time</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r6Lwr2y/)

Here is a simple hack. What I have done is added your right div inside left div, and it has done the trick.

```
<div id="menu">
<a href=""><img src="logo.svg"></a>
<div id="left">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>  
  <div id="right">
<ul>
   <li style="color:white">Date & Time</li>
</ul>
</div>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#menu {
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;   
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


#left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left li {
    float: left;
}

#left li a {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#right ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right li {
    float: right;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#right li span {
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#menu img{
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px
}
```